# Sequelize: How to insert data into newly created table after sync

Tags: javascript, sequelize.js

I basically want default settings populated in a table for my server to use on initial boot, or if the table were to be deleted.

How can I populate a table in sequelize after the sync method runs and only add the data once?

Comment: Do you mean after migrations?

Comment: @Moa OP is last active a year ago; so, I think you can try to give a generic answer with both case1. after migration / case2. no migration.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

basic example in [doc](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#count) show what you need exactly. you can extend it to check if your table has default entry or not by using [count](https://sequelize.org/docs/v6/core-concepts/model-querying-basics/#count)  then insert item/s.